# Which branch to select for rebasing

Tags: git, version-control, rebase

I've two simple branches named master and admin. History is shown below.

[image: History]

I simply want to take admin branch's updates to master without merge commits. Then I have two options. Which of the following should I need to follow?

1.Checkout to admin and `git rebase master` and fast-forward merge admin into master

2.Checkout to master and `git rebase admin`

### EDIT:

I found some other findings too (that may be a reason to choose a solution)

1. With option 1 it will remain master commits' SHA1 IDS without changing and change admin's SHA IDS
2. With option 2 it will do the opposite of above

So I think this is the main reason why we need to choose option 1, since we should not change the master's commits.

Comment: As others have said, you're after option 1. Here's how to remember: both `master` and `admin` have the same base initially (the "added index file" commit). You want to change the base of the `admin` branch, so that's the one you need to checkout and run `git rebase <other-commit>` on.

Comment: git rebase master should read like this: "take the current branch and make it start on the latest from master instead of a fork in the history"

Answer (score 1):

You want to do option 1. that will apply everything new that's in `admin` on top of the current state of `master`

Answer (score 1):

either way will work, but master branch is usually what others are working against as well if you are working with others. So from the admin branch, rebase it onto master:

```
git rebase master
```

Answer (score 0):

The resulting history (oldest commit on top) for both cases:

1. Checkout to admin and git rebase master and fast-forward merge admin into master

   ```
   added index file
   updated index
   admin added
   admin updated
   ```
2. Checkout to master and git rebase admin

   ```
   added index file
   admin added
   admin updated
   updated index
   ```

So, I think you want to use option 1